# Evaluate Row/Index Range of Identical Column Values in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Before going any further, there are a lot of answers relating 
to the question I am about to ask. As far as I can tell, none 
directly resolve my issue in a coherent manner.

Here is an example of my data:

```
Index     API     Measurement
    0     5       1000   
    1     5       2000
    2     5       30.1
    3     10      12
    4     12      0
    5     1       3123.1
    6     1       101.1
    7     100     3
    8     23      0
    9     23      123212.1
```

Here is what I want to do.
I want to - as simple and efficiently as possible - 
figure out the index RANGE of repeated API values.

Desired output:

```
API Index_RANGE
5   (0,2)
10  3
12  4
1   (5,6)
100 7
23  (8,9)
```

How do I go about accomplishing this?

Comment: Is 'Index' in the index or just a column named 'Index'?

Comment: By "repeated" do you mean subsequent, so If you had API = [1,1,2,2,1,1] you'd have 3 groups?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you require tuples or a single number, I'd write your own function, and pass It to `.agg`. Form groups finding where `'API'` changes:

```
def Index_RANGE(x):
    minx = x.index.min()
    maxx = x.index.max()
    if minx != maxx:
        return (minx, maxx)
    else:
        return minx

(df.groupby((df.API != df.API.shift(1)).cumsum()).API.agg(['first', Index_RANGE])
    .set_index('first').rename_axis('API'))
```

#### Output

```
    Index_RANGE
API            
5        (0, 2)
10            3
12            4
1        (5, 6)
100           7
23       (8, 9)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code produces your expected output exactly, but is not performant; it will slow down badly with increasing input data size (because of the list comprehension).

```
# Assume all repeated API values are contiguous;
# if not, first sort df by API
grouped = (df.groupby('API', sort=False)['Index']
            .agg(['first', 'last'])
            .itertuples(index=False, name=None))

pd.Series([x if x[0] != x[1] else x[0] for x in grouped],
           index=df.API.unique(), name='Index_RANGE')

5      (0, 2)
10          3
12          4
1      (5, 6)
100         7
23     (8, 9)
Name: Index_RANGE, dtype: object
```